# Return is completely ignored

Tags: php, ajax, return, echo

I have the following code

```
<?php   
    $token = '';
    if(!empty($_POST['token'])) $token = $_POST['token'];

    $url = '';
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['url'])) $url = Sanitize($_REQUEST['url']);

    if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) return 'erro1';
?>
```

This page is supposed to be executed by AJAX so I'm coding error codes, now if the URL is not valid, I expect it to return `erro1`

The problem is, it never returns `erro1`. I tried dumping the result of the filter_var and it was `false` as expected! The page simply executes and return nothing even though the URL is not valid, but if I switch return with an echo, it works.

Why is that?
Why is echo working but not return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `echo` instead of `return`. Your Web server executes the PHP code and serve its *output*, which you produce using `echo` and other printing functions.

Outside of a function, `return` [interrupts](http://php.net//manual/en/function.return.php) the script.

Answer (score 3):

`return` will return a value from a function to the the code that called that function. It can only be used internally within PHP.

Your `return` statement is not in a function.

To write data to the HTTP response where JavaScript can read it, you need to use `echo`, `print` or similar.